# How do I put a Button inside a Tab where indicator will stay in the correct tab?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, tabs

How do I put a button inside the Tab? If I'll click Homepage, it does go in the correct tab with the correct line indicator. However, if I'll click "Profile", the indicator will go to the log out button. How do I correct this where the indicator will stay on the correct tab? This is what it looks like if I'll go to the Profile Tab, the indicator will directly go to the Logout button.
[image: tab]

```
  const Header = (props) => {
  const { currentUser } = props;
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  // for the tab to stay on the correct path/page even if it was reloaded
  useEffect(() => {
    let path = window.location.pathname;
    if (path === "/" && value !== 0) setValue(0);
    else if (path === "/login" && value !== 1) setValue(1);
    else if (path === "/registration" && value !== 2) setValue(2);
    else if (path === "/profile" && value !== 2) setValue(2);
  }, [value]);


  const isMatch = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("md"));

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar>
        {/*  */}
        <Toolbar
          variant="dense">
          {isMatch ? (
            <h1>
              <div>
                <MobileviewComponent />
              </div>
            </h1>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <Grid>
                <Tabs
                  value={value}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                >

                  {currentUser && (
                    <Tab
                      disableRipple
                      label="Homepage"
                      to="/"
                      component={Link}
                    />
                  )}
                  {currentUser && (
                    <Tab
                      disableRipple
                      label="Profile"
                      to="/profile"
                      component={Link}
                    />
                  )}
                  {currentUser && (
                    <Button color="inherit" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
                      Logout
                    </Button>
                  )}

                  {!currentUser && (
                    <Tab
                      disableRipple
                      label="Homepage"
                      to="/"
                      component={Link}
                    />
                  )}
                  {!currentUser && (
                    <Tab
                      disableRipple
                      label="Login"
                      to="/login"
                      component={Link}
                    />
                  )}
                </Tabs>
              </Grid>
            </div>
          )}
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>

    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are setting state as `2` for both `/registration` and `/profile` so when you click on `/profile` tab value is set to `2` and I guess you are material-ui so the tabs count starts from `0`, hence `2` indicates `3rd` item in tabs and that is your `logout` button, hence it is highlighted